# jQuery empty only works on the second click after an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have two divs `.curation-contents-list`and `.film-contents-list`each with a list of links, when a link is clicked an AJAX call is made which appends some JSON data to a separate divs `.article-container` and `.project-container`. At the same time as the data is appended the div with the links where the link that was just clicked is hidden.

There is another div with the class `.panel-close` that can be clicked which removes the div with data that was just appended and makes the div containing the links reappear again. So everything is back to the original state

The problem is that it takes a second click on the `.panel-close` div to fire off the `.empty()` and `.show()` functions in my jQuery. Once this has been done the first time the jQuery works as it should. Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

My is the basic set up of my HTML:

```
<div class="curation-panel">
 <div class="curation-contents-list">
   <a class="load-article"></a>
 </div>

 <div class="article-container">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="film-panel">
 <div class="film-contents-list">
   <a class="load-project"></a>
 </div>

 <div class="project-container">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-close">
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.load-article').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var target  = $('.article-container');
  var url   =$(this).data('page') + '.json';

  $.get(url, function(data) {
    $('.curation-contents-list').hide();
    $(target).append(data);
    $("body").addClass("load-article-is-open"),
    $(this).animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 300, "easeInOutExpo")
  });
}),

$('.load-project').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var target  = $('.project-container');
  var url   =$(this).data('page') + '.json';

  $.get(url, function(data) {
    $('.film-contents-list').hide();
    $(target).append(data);
    $("body").addClass("load-project-is-open"),
    $(this).animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 300, "easeInOutExpo")
  });
}),

$(".panel-close").click(function() {
    $("body").removeClass("curation-panel-is-open").removeClass("film-panel-is-open").removeClass("load-article-is-open").removeClass("load-project-is-open"),
    $(".curation-panel").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 300, "easeInOutExpo"),
    $(".film-panel").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 300, "easeInOutExpo"),

    $('.curation-contents-list').show();
    $('.film-contents-list').show();
    $('.article-container').empty();
    $('.project-container').empty();
});
```

Comment: Try doing `$(".panel-close").on('click', functio...)...`? The reason i say this is because ive heard a lot of people say they have problems when using `.click`

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius Looking at jQuery's internals, `.click` is just a pass-through to the same binding that `on` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Andy that you should use semi-colons instead of commas for your line endings.  However, what's likely causing your issues is a missed dependency on the **jQuery Easing** library.  Check your console for errors such as

> `easeInOutExpo is not a function`

which would indicate that you're missing **[the jQuery Easing library](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-easing)**.

Just for a Proof of Concept, **[here's a working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/79hh2cLy/)**

And the relevant changes to the semi-colons:

```
$("body").removeClass("curation-panel-is-open film-panel-is-open load-article-is-open load-project-is-open");
$(".curation-panel").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
}, 300, "easeInOutExpo");
$(".film-panel").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
}, 300, "easeInOutExpo");
```

*Please note that I've removed the chain of `removeClass` and instead supplanted it with a spaced list instead.* There's no reason to re-call that function every time you want to remove a class on the same element.

Comment: You're correct the problem was the jQuery easing. Thank you so much for your help, would you mind explaining why the easing prevented it from working?

Comment: jQuery doesn't have native easing functions.  The easing library provides them.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick, give it a go. changed animate to scrolTop, put in semi-colons in the right places

```
$(".panel-close").click(function() {

$("body").removeClass("curation-panel-is-open").removeClass("film-panel-is-open").removeClass("load-article-is-open").removeClass("load-project-is-open");

$(".curation-panel").scrollTop( 300, "easeInOutExpo");

$(".film-panel").scrollTop( 300, "easeInOutExpo");

$('.curation-contents-list').show();
$('.film-contents-list').show();
$('.article-container').empty();
$('.project-container').empty();
});
```

you could also simplify the code by doing:

```
$(".panel-close").click(function() {

$("body").removeClass("curation-panel-is-open film-panel-is-open load-article-is-open load-project-is-open");


$(".film-panel, .curation-panel").scrollTop( 300, "easeInOutExpo");

$('.curation-contents-list, .film-contents-list').show();

$('.article-container, .project-container').empty();

});
```

(2nd method is untested)

Comment: Thank you Andy, that code is so much cleaner. It seems the problem was actually the jQuery easing as Josh mentioned in his answer